# Override Chargebee RedirectURL

Tags: subscription, recurring-billing

I'm using Chargebee's .NET library, and I want to override the redirectURL that I set up in my checkout page settings.

In the [documentation](https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/hosted_pages#checkout_new_subscription) they say that I can use HostedPage.CheckoutNew().RedirectURL("https://myredirecturl.com"), but there is no such parameter for me:

[image: missing returnurl parameter]

Am I doing something wrong, or its just missing from the .NET lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just released this option as a feature and it was deployed yesterday night.

We will release the updated client library within the next 2 days.

Check for the next release here :

https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-dotnet/releases